# Invalid column name exception

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

Im trying to get a simple SQL statement in my code, and get a `DataTable`, and for some reason I get this weird exception :

> Invalid column name

This is my code :

```
public DataTable GetAllVideoID(string stringId)
    {
        dt = new DataTable();
        dataObj = new DataObj();
        sql = "SELECT * FROM TBL_VIDEOS WHERE TBL_VIDEOS.ID=" + stringId;

        return dt = dataObj.SelectDataTable(sql);
    }

public DataTable SelectDataTable(string sql)
    {
        try
        {
            conn = new SqlConnection(conString);
            conn.Open();
            adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);

            dt = new DataTable();

            adapter.Fill(dt);



            return dt;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            throw e;
        }
        finally { conn.Close(); }

    }
```

When I run this on my management tool, just the statemnet - it works perfectly.
So I dunno ..

Structure of my DB :
ID,TITLE,V_DESCIPTION,UPLOAD_DATE,V_VIEW,USERNAME,RATING,V_SOURCE,FLAG

thanks :)

Comment: Could you show us the table structure of `TBL_VIDEOS`? Maybe one or more columns has a reserved word / keyword etc.?

Comment: Use sql-parameters to avoid sql-injection. Sidenote: You don't have to open/close a connection when using a DataAdapter. `Fill` will open/close it implicitely. Don't `throw exception` but only `throw` to keep the stack trace.

Comment: @TimSchmelter can you give me an example please?

Comment: @thormayer, msdn is your friend: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738521.aspx

Comment: @thormayer: These tips wouldn't answer this question, so i dont want to answer it.

Comment: the query seems right to me except if there are typo errors

Comment: Have you checked the value of `stringID`?

Comment: try to put a break point where `sql = "SELECT ` line and inspect the value of `sql`. I suspect the `stringId`

Comment: stringId returning something that does not exists in the Table, and I want that the DataTable Row will check afterwards if its exists or not..

Comment: But ID is a numeric field, right? What is the value of your stringID? "-1", "0" or something that could give problems like a string text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

changing your sql to

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM TBL_VIDEOS WHERE TBL_VIDEOS.ID='" + stringId+"'";
```

could fix this. That puts a single quote around the value of stringId e.g. `.ID = '10'`

If stringId = 'user' your query becomes

```
 sql = "SELECT * FROM TBL_VIDEOS WHERE TBL_VIDEOS.ID=user
 instead of
 sql = "SELECT * FROM TBL_VIDEOS WHERE TBL_VIDEOS.ID = 'user'
```

but user is not a valid variable in sql, so you get invalid column name

Comment: thank you .  it seems like I wanted to pass a string instead of an int.

Comment: @thormayer Your column name is very confusing. ID is not typically a string. (We also don't really need a TBL_ prefix to know that a table is a table.)

Answer (score 0):

Your `SelectDataTable` method is absolutely fine.
The only thing which comes to my mind is to replace this:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM TBL_VIDEOS WHERE TBL_VIDEOS.ID=" + stringId;
```

by

```
sql = string.Format("SELECT * FROM TBL_VIDEOS WHERE TBL_VIDEOS.ID 
        = '{0}'", stringId);
```